# How to acces all objects via Python in the Game Engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have different objects in a scene and I want to control them with python code. My question is? Do I have to create a script for every object or I can control all of them with only one python script? I've tried with only one script but then there is only one object as the controller... and I need to change the properties of an object that is not the "controller". I don't know if I explained this well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access all objects from the scene by its name:

```
import GameLogic
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
obj=scene.objects['ObjectName']
```

To access the vertices:

```
import GameLogic


scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
obj=scene.objects['Cube']

mesh = obj.meshes[0]

for v in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(0)):
    vert = mesh.getVertex(0, v)
    print( "%d,%d,%d" % ( vert.x, vert.y, vert.z ))

print( dir( vert ))
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need to access to the vertex of the object and using scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene() I can't do getVertex because is not defined

Comment: You should call `print( dir ( obj ))` to see what is available. Added access to vertices to the answer.